# Azure Ubuntu VM new release available

Tags: linux, azure

I have two Ubuntu VMs running in Azure. One is our test server and the other is production. I've just `sudo apt updgrade` on our test server and rebooted and the message I'm getting now is `New release '18.04.1 LTS' available.` When I run `do-release-upgrade` I get the following output:

> Checking package manager
>
> Continue running under SSH?
>
> This session appears to be running under ssh. It is not recommended 
>   to perform a upgrade over ssh currently because in case of failure it 
>   is harder to recover.
>
> If you continue, an additional ssh daemon will be started at port 
>   '1022'.  Do you want to continue?
>
> Continue [yN]

So Azure has a Serial Console in preview. I tried starting that and I get the following message:

> The serial console connection to the VM encountered an error: 'Not
>   Found' (404) - Unable to retrieve boot diagnostics settings for
>   'server name'. To use serial console, ensure that boot diagnostics is
>   enabled for this VM.

So what are the implications of enabling boot diagnostics on my test and production servers? Is it a good practice to enable boot diagnostics on a production server and is a restart required? I'm looking for some useful guidance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> what are the implications of enabling boot diagnostics on my test and
>   production servers? Is it a good practice to enable boot diagnostics
>   on a production server and is a restart required?

You can enable boot diagnostics on your VM to capture logs that can help you troubleshoot boot failure and have a screenshot to see the VM's current status. For Linux virtual machines, you can easily view the output of your console log from the Portal.

Besides, if you enable boot Boot diagnostics on existing virtual machine, you have to restart the VM to take effect.

References: [How to use boot diagnostics to troubleshoot Windows virtual machines in Azure](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/windows/boot-diagnostics)

Comment: So this is recommended but requires a reboot to enable it?

Comment: Yes, recommended, the boot diagnostics log will be stored in your storage account blob. If you have not enabled the boot diagnostics when you create the virtual machine although the default is enabled. You have to restart the existing VM to enable it.

Comment: Thanks - follow up question. I can now access the console but I can't login to VM using azureuser & password from the portal console. Normally we access the VM using ssh. What do I need to do to enable password authentication for azureuser at the Console?

Comment: Find your virtual machine control panel in the portal, select the `reset password` under Support + troubleshooting blade. Select Reset password mode, type username and password. Then you can use this password to login to console.